Multi-level Linear Mixed Model: Sampling and Power Issues
I am struggling to find a proper model for my analysis, and on top of this, I have some questions about the number of observations and the resulting power of the model.
Experiment
I ran a reaction time (RT) experiment on $n = 32$ participants, which all underwent four sessions comprising 2x2 conditions (i.e. two independent variables, varA and varB). The reaction time task has 3 cue types (invalid, neutral, valid) in order from slow response to fast. And then finally there are 2 visual fields: left and right. The outcome variable I’m looking for is thus reaction time.
Now, as a sanity check, RT on valid trials should be significantly higher than neutral trials + invalid trials significantly slower than neutral trials. Independent variable A should result in an increased reaction time benefit of valid trials. And we expect no difference in visual field, therefore it is a sanity check too.
Preprocessing
I remove trials with RTs that are too fast as well as incorrect responses. This means that some combination of variables leave me with 1 trial. Some condition cells have the full number of 16 or 32 trials.
Initially I tried taking the median reaction time within each condition cell and then running a mixed linear model, after which I check each factor using the anova() function of lmerTest in R. But after much consideration, I now tend towards using a multi-level linear mixed model to keep as much as the collected information (read: the individual trials) intact. Intuitively a multilevel model entails more of the information (variance if you will) than running an ANOVA, where you take the median first. But please correct me if I'm wrong.
Model
model.null <- lmer(rt ~ (1 | participant), data = df, na.action=na.omit)

model.full <- lmer(rt ~ (1 | participant) + (valid+invalid) * visual_field + varA * varB, data = df, na.action=na.omit)

Note that I made a dummy for the valid + invalid trials where valid is 1 with all valid trials (rest is 0) and invalid is 1 with all invalid trials (rest is 0). That way I can easily compare both with neutral cues, which is in this case the most meaningful pair of comparisons.
Issues and questions
Now, if I run this model on the trial-level data (thus, multilevel model) it contains around 30,000 degrees of freedom and all effects are highly significant. I wonder whether using this approach will make me run into super inflated power issues and thereby increased Type I error risk.
Now, at this level, I think there are multiple “rights” but I am really curious to your perspective on this matter. How should I analyze these data most correctly? What are the caveats of this approach in terms of power? Is the model OK to start with? Should I throw away combinations with only 1 trial? What is the minimum amount of RT trials for a condition cell (combination) to be included?

There is a lot of stuff going on here. I'll try my best to answer your question, but I don't know if I can sufficiently answer everything.
First off, I see that you have simply kicked out your missing data with the na.omit argument in lmer. Don't do this. You need to first investigate what is causing the missingness, then find a way to meaningfully deal with it (usually via some form of imputation, preferably something like multiple imputation with packages like mice).
Second, I'm going to go on a whim and say your four-way interaction here is probably totally unnecessary. Is there a reason you believe this should be present? In any case, you have entered valid trials as a main effect and invalid trials separately as another main effect, both of which interact with the other three variables with *. This isn't doing what you think. If you really want trials entered in the model, it should really be a single variable that is dummy-coded (or whatever coding you prefer) so it can be "toggled on and off" in the regression. What you currently have doesn't do that.
Third, the number of observations isn't a problem, but I am confused about how you got there. If you have 32 subjects and you are only estimating their random effect clusters, then there shouldn't be any increase in observations. This would occur if you had something like a subject x trial random effect design (where both are entered into the model), but you don't have that here. Whatever the case is, having more observations isn't a problem...so long as you are not creating a bunch of redundant data in your model, which I'm afraid may be the case, depending on the structure of your data.
Fourth, how did you decide on trials that were too quick? If you mean these are invalid (some impossible number like -300 ms), then I would see an argument here. But if it is simply too quick relative to other measurements, I'm not sure this is a great idea to do. If they are outliers, then you can just utilize more robust methods for estimating the model...if they are indeed a problem to begin with.
Fifth, I'm not sure if your commentary on anova() is related to the model comparison function used in lmerTest or ANOVAs in general (the wording makes it seem you mean the former). If you are referring to the function, this just runs a likelihood ratio test on different models and tests whether or not one model is preferred over another. You would only do this if you want to test whether or not a fitted model is superior to a null model, such as the one you have constructed. If you are just asking about whether one should use ANOVA here, just don't use the ANOVA for repeated measures. It requires things like sphericity, and that is usually not realistic. Mixed models don't have this problem.
Finally, just to nitpick, you should never say the words "highly significant." This implies significance is a magnitude. Under the typical NHST framework, an estimate is either significant or non-significant based off if it passes the alpha cutoff. How low a $p$-value becomes after that doesn't make it more or less significant.
